# Finding all "X-generation" descendants using jQuery

Tags: jquery, children, descendant

### Solved (*sort of*)

Well, I think I solved it (*barring edge cases*) using the following:

```
function findByDepth(parent, child, depth){
    var children = $();
    $(child, $(parent)).each(function(){
        if($(this).parentsUntil(parent, child).length == (depth - 1)){
            children = $(children).add($(this));
        }
    });
    return children;
}

// this would successfully return the 3.X elements of an HTML snippet structured
// as my XML example, where <parent> = #parent, etc.
var threeDeep = findByDepth('#parent', '.child', 3);
```

However *somebody* has to get the accepted answer here, and I'm not going to answer it myself and abscond with your well earned rep. So, if anyone wants to add anything, such as provide insight into optimizing this function (*before I go and `$.extend()` it in*) I'll likely mark your answer correct, otherwise falling back to marking whoever was first on my initial question.

By the way, check it in the fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/5PDaA/](http://jsfiddle.net/5PDaA/6/)

**Sub-update**

Looking again at @CAFxX's answer, I realized that his approach is probably faster, taking advantage of `querySelectorAll` in browsers that can. Anyways, I revised his approach to the following, yet it's still giving me guff:

```
$.fn.extend({
    'findAtDepth': function(selector, depth){
        var depth = parseInt(depth) || 1;
        var query = selector;
        for(var i = 1; i < depth; i++){
            query += (' ' + selector);
        }
        return $(query, $(this)).not(query + ' ' + selector);
    }
});
```

It works fine the first time, however as context changes to an element found in the `selector`, it fails for some reason.

---

### Update

Alright, I was foolishly unclear, and uninformed as to the specs for what I'm doing. Since I've reviewed my implementation I'll update here; I'll mark the earliest answer that meets my initial requirements given people think me a fool for updating so gratuitously (*I wouldn't blame you*) however my *bonus* mention below is essentially a requirement. I'd post another question, but it'd likely get closed from duplication. Regardless, +1's all around for your patience:

**Depth specification** of a given child is necessary (*given it's wrapped in a function or otherwise*) thus isolating a child and equally nested (*not necessarily siblings*) matching elements.

For instance (*XML for brevity*):

```
<!-- depth . sibling-index-with-respect-to-depth -->

<parent>
    <child>                     <!-- 1.1 -->
        <child>                 <!-- 2.1 -->
            <child>             <!-- 3.1 -->
                <child></child> <!-- 4.1 -->
            </child>            
            <child>             <!-- 3.2 -->
                <child></child> <!-- 4.2 -->
            </child>            
        </child>                
        <child>                 <!-- 2.2 -->
            <child></child>     <!-- 3.3 -->
        </child>                
    </child>                    
</parent>
```

Given a depth specified of `2`, all `2.X` elements are selected. Given `4` all `4.X`, and so on.

---

### Original Question

Using the native functionality of jQuery, is there a way to select only the "first-generation" of descendants matching a selector? For instance:

***Note**: The following is only an example. `.child` elements are nested in a parent at an arbitrary level.*

***Bonus**: As my proposed syntax below indicates, an answer that provides a way to specify a depth to which the selection should traverse would be **incredible**.*

```
// HTML
<div id="parent">
    <div>
        <div class="child"> <!-- match -->
            <div>
                <div class="child"> <!-- NO match -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child"> <!-- match -->
            <div>
                <div class="child"> <!-- NO match -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
// jQuery
$('#parent').find('.child:generation(1)'); // something in that vein
```

Trying to select from the context of `#parent`, the jQuery `:first` doesn't work here as it only hits the first matched `.child`.

Comment: is the depth of child arbitrary, or will it always be in a div? `#parent>div>.child` will work for this example

Comment: Thanks @Andy Ray - Just updated to reflect; yes, arbitrary depth. Could be an immediate child, could be several levels deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (KISS!):

```
$("#parent .child").not(".child .child");
```

edit: to get the second level:

```
$("#parent .child .child").not(".child .child .child");
```

the third:

```
$("#parent .child .child .child").not(".child .child .child .child");
```

and so on... so you could have (untested):

```
function findChildrenDeepDown(parentSelector, level) {
  level = parseInt(level);
  var firstSelctor = parent, notSelector = ".child", i;
  for (i=0; i<level; i++) {
    firstSelector += " .child";
    notSelector += " .child";
  }
  return $(firstSelector).not(notSelector);
}

findChildrenDeepDown("#parent", 3); // find third-level children of #parent
```

Comment: Thanks @CAFxX - That appears to do the job. Any suggestions on the *bonus* I updated above? Perhaps some sort of iteration using the `.not()` or `:not()` method?

Comment: there you go, not very elegant but it should work. you could wrap it in a function that concatenates `" .child"` N times (with N the desired depth) and then invokes the `$()`.

Comment: You know, this is probably the least computationally expensive method. Traversing the tree both ways, rifling through elements to isolate a given depth can get expensive, but this shouldn't be.

Comment: There is a more elegant way : `$("#parent").find(".child").siblings();` (as said in my post)

Comment: Hm, doesn't appear to be working; the `.not()` clause is interfering with a depth specification greater than 1.

Comment: Thanks @CAFxX - Still appears to be a problem (*I know you mentioned your edit is untested, however I revised it with no luck still*) I'll post it up in the question, as I'm still having trouble with this; my proposed solution doesn't appear to be working properly either.

Comment: @Bracketworks I guess your `findAtDepth` doesn't work because the `.not()` is not relative to the element you're starting from. Suppose you execute it on a .parent .child .child, asking for `.child` 2 layers deeper: the `$()` would correctly return them (along their `.child` descendants), but the `.not(".child .child .child")` would filter them all out because they really are `.parent .child .child .child .child .child`

Answer (score 1):

you can get it like this :

```
$("#parent").find(">div>.child")
```

---

EDIT

If first child can be in a random depth, you can use

```
$("#parent").find(".child").siblings();
```

Comment: Thanks @Arnaud F. - As per Andy's comment, I updated the question; the `.child` elements can exist an an arbitrary depth with respect to the `#parent`. Also, to the -1'er; likely not warranted, his answer was pre-update.

Comment: this will only work if you are guaranteed to have two top level children to find, and if there aren't any bottom level children that are next to each other

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think you'd have to find all of the `.child` elements and then throw away those that have `.child` ancestors:

```
$('#parent .child').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parent().closest('.child').length == 0;
});
```

This doesn't handle things like this though:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"> <!-- match -->
        <div>
            <div class="child"> <!-- NO match -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="child"> <!-- NO match wanted but it will match -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but maybe it will be sufficient for the structure of your HTML.

Comment: Thanks @mu - This is moving in a good direction; CAFxX's response solves the initial problem, and certainly is KISS-able, however a programmatic approach will provide more flexibility as my *bonus* update calls for.

Comment: Big ole' pile of nested elements, but as my *bonus* mentions (*which is really more of a requirement as I consider the implementation*) the ability to specify the depth with respect to the selector (*`.child` or whatever*) would be great. I see where you're going; probably `$('.child:first').siblings('.child')`, but depth specification would be great.

Comment: @Bracketworks: You could skip jQuery and do a BFS through the DOM to find your starting `.child` and then go sideways to get the rest at that depth; then pile 'em all together with `x=$();x.add()`; might not be pretty but it should work. BTW, answering your own question is fine, as is accepting your own answer (there's even a [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner) for that sort of thing).